# How to add Teensy board to VS Code and Arduino plugin?

Tags: macos, arduino, visual-studio-code, teensy

I am currently programming a Teens y2.0 using the Arduino IDE with Teensyduino. It works but Arduino IDE is rubbish, so I would like to use VS Code. However while the Arduino VS code plugin works fine, it doesn't recognise the Teensy as a board, even though Teensyduino installs its libraries etc into the Arduino IDE package.

Does anyone know how to add Teensy support to VS Code or an alternative IDE I can use that will recognise the board?

OSX Sierra / VS Code with vscode-arduino plugin v0.24 / Teensy 2.0

Comment: My workaround, though cluggy, was to disable the VS Code plugin, install a C/C++ language plugin, create a blank sketch with Arduino IDE, set it to use an external editor, and then edit the sketch using VSCode, but build using the ArduinoIDE.

Comment: I've been trying to figure this one out. @AJ how difficult was it to set it up with your editor / build settings? Could you post this as a potential solution with the steps involved?

Comment: This is an old question but still ranks high on Google when searching - just FYI there is a VSCode plugin called PlatformIO that supports Teensy from VSCode now - works great.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [PlatformIO](https://platformio.org/) with Visual Studio Code (or with many other major IDEs, or even from the command line). PlatformIO is a build system (sort of like Make, but with a lot more power) for all kinds of embedded platforms.

To get started:

- Run Visual Studio Code
- Choose Preferences / Extensions
- Search for "PlatformIO" and click **Install**
- Reload VS Code when prompted
- In the PIO Home window, click on the BOARDS icon
- Find your Teensy board. Look in the **Platform** column and click on **Teensy** there.
- This will take you to a screen where you can install the **Teensy** Platform.

To see it working:

- Go to the PIO Home (There is a little house icon in the lower left of your VS Code window if you lost it)
- Click **Project Examples**
- Select Teensy > Arduino Blink
- Find the **platformio.ini** file it gives you, and delete all the extra sections *except* for your particular Teensy board
- In the lower left corner of the VS Code screen, you'll see a checkmark icon which builds and a right arrow icon which installs the HEX file on your Teensy, just like the Arduino editor.

*You will still need Teensyduino!*

[Hat tip to Mikah Barnett for the answer in the comments]